# R : RQuantLib not calculating greeks

Tags: r, quantlib

I'm trying to use the `RQuantLib` package to calculate greeks for some options but getting `NAs` for all the output values except price.

I'm getting the same results when I copy the examples from the package user manual:

```
> AmericanOption("put", strike=100, volatility=0.4, 100, 0.02, 0.03, 0.5)
Concise summary of valuation for AmericanOption 
  value   delta   gamma    vega   theta     rho  divRho 
10.9174      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA 
> AmericanOption("call", 100, 100, 0.02, 0.03, 0.5, 0.4)
Concise summary of valuation for AmericanOption 
  value   delta   gamma    vega   theta     rho  divRho 
11.3648      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has been discussed before [e.g. in this thread on the r-sig-finance mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.finance/9397): the stubs are there because QL used to provided (numerical) greeks for American options, but stopped doing so many years ago.

So you have to approximate them numerically by shifting inputs; see the post referenced above for details.  Consider subscribing to r-sig-finance as well.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel, I'm trying to learn how to use RQuantLib and have reviewed the related discussion on [https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rquantlib/issues/154#issuecomment-922188121], but am also trying to follow your comment above, but the link to r-sig-finance mailing list (of which I am a recent part) seems now to be broken.  Is there an update?

Comment: Yes, gmane.org as a 'nicer' interface to the mailing list went away.  The official site is still there:  https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to include the engine CrankNicolson as follows:

```
# simple call with unnamed parameters, using Crank-Nicolons
AmericanOption("put", strike=100, volatility=0.4, 100, 0.02, 0.03, 0.5, engine="CrankNicolson")
```