# How to get RQuantLib use QuantLib1.7 instead of 1.4 on windows

Tags: r, quantlib

For Greeks calculations, I am using RQuantLib_0.4.2 which I installed with `install.packages()`.

When running the program, the following is printed:

> ```
> Loading required package: RQuantLib
> QuantLib version 1.4 detected which is older than 1.7.
> Intra-daily options analytics unavailable with that version
> ```

What am I missing to get RQuantLib_0.4.2 to use QuantLib_1.7 on Windows 7?  Do I need to manually install QunatLib_1.7?

Comment: Yes, in order to use QuantLib 1.7 you need to install it. See [www.quantlib.org](http://www.quantlib.org)

Comment: It is what I asked you twice...

Comment: Information on http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rquantlib.html is little misleading as installing the Quantlib is mandated on linux only

Comment: @Pascal : are you sure updating the version will resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Dirk's [blog post](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2015/12/03/#rquantlib_0.4.2) that you mentioned in a [comment on a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629345/rquantlib-is-returning-vega-theta-rho-divrho-na#comment57005393_34629345) tells you what needs to be done:

> a volunteer is needed to update the QuantLib 1.7 build for Windows.
>   Jeroen tried, but ran into a snag and out of time. If you can help,
>   please get in touch to Jeroen and myself. We suspect that the largest
>   part of RQuantLib users relies on the prebuilt binaries from CRAN, and
>   it would nice to have these updated to the current version of
>   QuantLib.

Comment: And to extend this:  we could do with Windows build help for the just-released QuantLib 1.8 as well.